# i try to open a text file from my local machine using java script but in console it showing console error

Tags: jquery, ajax

- my txt file is in the same folder where i created my html file.
- txt file contains simply some dumb texts.
- After clicking button it showing console error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/hai.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: You might want to share your code, if you want any help.

Comment: Also, shorten your title and clarify your question please.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a local file with JavaScript. It is a security measure. If it was possible, any site could actually load any file on your Pc.

If you need to store/retrieve some application data, use local storage

Comment: That depends on what you mean by _open a local file_. Loading a text file's content into a HTML element on your page, from your site's root is absolutely possible.

Comment: Yes, but question says : "i try to open a text file from my local machine ", intended "web page" to local